# Creating threads in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, multithreading

How to make a new thread and initiate start of SrcGrabber.grabSource() in the main file? And what type of thread should I use? Without another thread this code doesn't work.
In the main file I just need to do SrcGrabber.grabSource() and continue with returned mBuffer.toString().

```
public class SrcGrabber {
private HttpGet mRequest;
private HttpClient mClient;
private BufferedReader mReader;

private DocumentBuilder mBuilder;

private StringBuffer mBuffer;
private String mNewLine;

public SrcGrabber() {
    mRequest = new HttpGet();
    mClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    mReader = null;

    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        mBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mBuffer = new StringBuffer(2000);
    mNewLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
}

public String grabSource(String url) throws ClientProtocolException,
        IOException, URISyntaxException {
    mBuffer.setLength(0);

    try {
        mRequest.setURI(new URI("http://www.bash.im"));
        HttpResponse response = mClient.execute(mRequest);
        mReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
                .getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = mReader.readLine()) != null) {
            mBuffer.append(line);
            mBuffer.append(mNewLine);
        }
    } finally {
        closeReader();
    }

    return mBuffer.toString();
}

private void closeReader() {
    if (mReader == null)
        return;

    try {
        mReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't know what your *"main file"* is but assuming it's an `Activity` then consider converting your `SrcGrabber` class to extend `AsyncTask`. Other than that, you can read about Threads here...http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to read this Blog Article: [Android Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2009/05/painless-threading.html).

It explains the different ways possible in Android.

Comment: +1 for that link - I was trying to find that one but didn't have it in my browser bookmarks.

Comment: I had to google it myself, but the title is quite catchy so I remembered it :-)

Comment: But I can't understand how I can get data that this function returns if it's in another thread.

Comment: _onPreExecute(), onPostExecute() and onProgressUpdate() are all invoked on the UI thread_